# How to render a texture with alpha?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, textures, alpha

How to render a texture with alpha?

I have a texture, and need to render it with different alpha values at different locations. Any way to do so? (My texture is GL_RGBA)

If not possible to change alpha value on the fly, I have to create different textures for different alpha levels?

Comment: What structure holds the image?

Comment: i have a DIB data (converted from HBITMAP), then i create the texture from DIB, but the DIB data is deleted just right after creating texture. (ie: free(dib_data_handle);)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your texture is GL_RGBA so it *has* a different alpha value for each texel.

If you want to change the alpha value used for render, I can think of the following methods:

- Change the texture alpha values (not sure if you say that you don't want to do that).
- Use `glColor4f` to change the alpha value of the vertices. It will multiply the texture values. You may need to use `glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)` and/or `glColorMaterial()`.
- Use a vertex shader to change the vertex alpha values. It will multiply the texture values.
- Use a fragment shader to change the sampled texture values on the fly.
- Use two texture stages and multiply them. The second one will have the modified alpha values (see `glActiveTexture()` and friends).
- Use a fragment shader and two (or more) texture stages. This is the coolest!

Comment: what i want is to reduce the alpha by half from every pixel, which solution should i choose?

Comment: Just glColor4f(1,1,1, 0.5f) should do that, provided that the color is enabled.

Comment: do i need to enable GL_BLEND, and i must use GL_MODULATE when generate texture?

Comment: Probably yes and yes. Also, if you have enabled GL_LIGHTING, you will want to enable GL_COLOR_MATERIAL also, so glColor does something useful.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure that your texture has an alpha channel. You mention you are loading an RGBA format, but it's always good to check the original file in an image editing program. Then make sure your texture is ready for rendering in openGL. A common mistake is to forget to set up the texture's filtering mode through `glTexParameter*`. It starts on a setting requiring mipmaps, so I find that it's easiest to start with:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Secondly, you will need to set up openGL to be ready for blending. This involves a `glEnable` call with `GL_BLEND` and a `glBlendFunc` call. Most of the time, you will want the function call to be `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`, as most other combinations of tokens will give you effects you are not after (see the [`glBlendFunc`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml) spec page for more info).

Finally, ensure you are sampling your texture at different points. If you are using immediate mode (you are using `glVertex*` to draw your scene), you will need to either use `glTexGen*` or manually specify texture points using `glTexCoord*` before calls to `glVertex*`. If using array data to draw your scene, make sure you have enabled the texture pointer using `glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)` and `glTexCoordPointer`.