# How to create a texture alpha, with white and black colors only, in GLSL?

Tags: glsl, shader, scenekit

I am looking to reproduce the glow effect from this [tutorial](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch21.html), if I understand well, we convert the first image to an "alpha texture" (black and white), and we blur the (rgb * a) texture.

How is it possible to create this alpha texture, so that some colors go to the white, and the other go to the black? I found this : [How to render a texture with alpha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332162/how-to-render-a-texture-with-alpha) but I don't really know how to use these answers.

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are misunderstanding what that diagram is showing you. It is actually all one texture, but `(a)` shows the RGB color and `(b)` shows the alpha channel. `(c)` shows what happens when you multiply RGB by A.

Alpha is not actually "black and white", it is an abstract concept and amounts to a range of values between **0.0** and **1.0**. For the human brain to make sense out of it, it interprets that as black (**0.0**) and white (**1.0**). In reality, alpha is whatever you want it to be and unrelated to color (though it can be used to do something to color).

Typically the alpha channel would be generated by a post-process image filter, that looks for areas of the texture with significantly above average luminance. In modern graphics engines HDR is used and any part of the scene with a color too bright to be displayed on a monitor is a candidate for glowing. The intensity of this glow is derived from just how much brighter the lighting at that point is than the monitor can display.

In this case, however, it appears to be human created. Think of the alpha channel like a mask, some artist looked at the UFO and decided that the areas that appear non-black in figure `(b)` were supposed to glow so a non-zero alpha value was assigned (with alpha = **1.0** glowing the brightest).

---

Incidentally, you should not be blurring the alpha mask. You want to blur the ***result*** of RGB * A. If you just blurred the alpha mask, then this would not resemble glowing at all. The idea is to blur the lit parts of the UFO that are supposed to glow and then add that on top of the base UFO color.

Comment: Thanks, so the mix texture of a) and b) should be created only once, is it done with "buffers"? I read about "frame buffer" which uses 3 buffers (color, depth, stencil) but it is bit confusing now. Let's say I created a "buffer" with the new image, where should I put this code? I use SceneKit, the material can have a shader associated, which let me have access to the vertex and the fragment shaders, but they are both called at each frame I guess.

Comment: @Paul: There is a lot of fundamental stuff you are missing, unfortunately. Implementing a blur filter and glow might be something you put on hold while you study the OpenGL 3.0 / OpenGL ES 2.0 render pipeline. I mean this genuinely, you are going to need to understand what Framebuffer Objects, Renderbuffer Objects and Texture Objects are to properly implement a glow/bloom filter. You might get lucky and piece together enough working shader code from a bunch of tutorials, but you really need to understand the basics first.

Comment: @Paul: Regarding your question about mixing `a)` and `b)`, if you use a static glow map (one that an artist comes up with) it would be done once. However, a modern graphics engine does this dynamically using an image processing filter in a fragment shader. That would definitely be done using a Framebuffer Object to store the results of the fragment shader in either a Renderbuffer or a Texture. And you are correct, the traditional framebuffer contains color, depth and stencil (sometimes even accumulation), but in modern OpenGL and GL ES you can define your own using Framebuffer Objects.

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried a bit but I might try again another day, I opened a thread on gameDev stack exchange : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/96795/how-to-generate-a-rgb-a-texture-for-a-glow-effect-in-glsl , but I could not have more answers to continue :-). Thanks for the answers.